# NPE for JobExecution#getJobName

Tags: batch-processing, jberet

In my application, I use JBeret implementation for batch processing.

When trying to retrieve the running executions of a job but I got a NPE:

Stacktrace:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at org.jberet.runtime.JobExecutionImpl.getJobName(JobExecutionImpl.java:141)
>           at org.jberet.operations.JobOperatorImpl.getRunningExecutions(JobOperatorImpl.java:157)
>           at ch.adnovum.monexio.server.batch.rs.BatchOperatorServiceBean.getRunningJobIds(BatchOperatorServiceBean.java:143)
>           at ch.adnovum.monexio.server.batch.rs.BatchOperatorServiceBean.assertAtomicJob(BatchOperatorServiceBean.java:94)
>           at ch.adnovum.monexio.server.batch.rs.BatchOperatorServiceBean.start(BatchOperatorServiceBean.java:54)

The code for your reference: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jberet/jberet-core/1.0.1.CR1/org/jberet/operations/JobOperatorImpl.java#JobOperatorImpl.getRunningExecutions%28java.lang.String%29

I checked the database where JBeret stores the job information, as far as I can see, the every execution attached to valid instance.

[image]

Has anyone ever faced the same problem?

Answer (score -1):

See JBeret project issue page https://github.com/jberet/jsr352/issues/81 for more discussion and answer.

This problem only occurs with WildFly 8.2.0.Final and older version of JBeret.  It looks like some problem during deserializaing job execution data from db.

If someone else is also seeing this problem, please upgrade to more recent versions of WildFly and JBeret.